# How to enable ACL?

Tags: linux, permissions, acl

I've installed ACL on my Ubuntu:

```
aptitude install acl
```

What is the next step ? /etc/fstab ?

```
  # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
    #
    # Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
    # for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
    # devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
    #
    # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
    proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
    # / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
    UUID=54dd976c-b95d-4f44-b4f7-516107dbed85 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
    # swap was on /dev/sda2 during installation
    UUID=b03c5549-9b4a-444f-a1ff-6c1e3c767836 none            swap    sw              0       0
    /dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

ext4 ACL are not enabled by default (at least on a debian squeeze). So, your way is to add the *acl* option in your */etc/fstab*

```
…
UUID=54dd976c-b95d-4f44-b4f7-516107dbed85 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro,acl ,0       1
…
```

… and to avoid a reboot, you can apply it immediatly :

```
# mount -oremount /
```

(can't believe it's not enabled by default…)

Comment: And do not forget that you should have root access.

Comment: If you do this, should `mount | grep acl` return something?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

[`getfacl(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getfacl)

[`setfacl(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl)

Some filesystems may need `acl` added to their mount options, but I believe most use it by default.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams i have edited my question, please take a look at the fstab. Do I have to change something ? thank you

Comment: Some filesystems may need `acl` added to their mount options, but I believe most use it by default.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams ok perfect! last question... if I set permission to /home/test... also all the directory inside this will have the same permissions, right?

Comment: ACLs take effect per filesystem object, and `setfacl` is *not* recursive by default.

Comment: OMG, if i have 300 directories inside i have to write 300 time setfacl? :-(

Comment: Or you could just use `find`...

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams If in this directory an ftp server upload files and directories, I would like to extend ACL permissions also to these future files/directories, how could i do?

Comment: You'd have to use a tool that watches for filesystem changes and applies the ACLs.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams any advice?