# chroot an user to more than one directory in different locations

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, chroot, chroot-jail

I would like to know how I can constraint a user to only be able to access and have RWX permissions to directories like `/etc/httpd`, `/etc/php` and `/var/www/html` as well as its own home directory.

Also I would like to be able to constraint this user to be able to only star/stop/restart apache service.

All I could think of is chroot, but I have just done that with one directory. Any ideas?

Comment: How about regular file permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `chroot`  won't help here. I think [acl](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/storage_administration_guide/acls-setting) is what you're looking for, but he will still have at least read access to the rest of the file system. `chroot`is very powerful but it practically defines a new root `/` directory and that's it. `ACL` on the other hand, allows you to do something like `setfacl -R -m u:user:rw /etc/httpd/*` and allow the user to edit all files under `/etc/httpd/`. You'll have to [enable](https://superuser.com/questions/275514/how-to-enable-acl) `ACL` for the file system first, if it's not already enabled.

Regarding services, `sudo` is most probably the tool that will fit your purpose. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692701/allowing-user-to-run-systemctl-systemd-services-without-password#692712) is an example of how to achieve this.